# How to remove a top level menu in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'd like to work in a minimalist manner.  So I am trying to remove some of the top level menus that I do not use.

I don't see anything obvious in the Customize window.  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.  Go back to Customize (right-click in the menu or toolbar areas), then choose the "Commands" tab instead of the default "Toolbars".

With the "Menu Bar" option selected, you can delete, move, or create high-level menu items, or dive into each menu and customize items.  If you make a mistake, click Reset All.

For minimalist coding, I'm also a fan of Full Screen mode (VIEW -> Full Screen or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).